# creating random questions for a worksheet

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, pstricks, mathspec

This might be too much to ask but I would like to create a worksheet like the one below,

```
\documentclass{article}
%AdditionCode
% \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xlop}
\usepackage{pstricks}
% \usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{~\\56 Problem Practice Worksheet}
\rhead{Name: ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ \\}
\lfoot{Number Correct: ~ \Large $\dfrac{~}{56}$}
\cfoot{~}

%---------------------------------------%
% To change the Difficulty, enter a number.
% Problems will be generated randomly with 
% this as a maximum (i.e. 99 will give all
% two-digit numbers). Default is for First
%and Second number to be single digit (i.e.
%maximum of 9).
\newcommand*{\DifficultyOne}{99}%
\newcommand*{\DifficultyTwo}{99}%
%---------------------------------------%
\newcommand{\AddQuestion}[1]{%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{%

      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnea}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoa}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOneb}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwob}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnec}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoc}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOned}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwod}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnee}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoe}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnef}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwof}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOneg}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwog}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOneh}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoh}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
  
       \hspace*{\fill}
       \opadd[carryadd=false, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\white]{\AddOnea}       {\AddTwoa} \hfill  \opadd[carryadd=false, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\white] {\AddOneb}{\AddTwob} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=false, voperator=bottom,  resultstyle=\white]{\AddOnec}{\AddTwoc} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=false, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\white]{\AddOned}{\AddTwod} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=false, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\white]{\AddOnee}{\AddTwoe} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=false, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\white]{\AddOnef}{\AddTwof} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=false, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\white]{\AddOneg}{\AddTwog} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=false, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\white]{\AddOneh}{\AddTwoh}  \hspace*{\fill}\\
          ~\newline
          ~\newline

 }%
 }%

 \begin{document}
 %\large
 \AddQuestion{7}

 \end{document}
```

but with  sums involving DIDMAS

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{amsmath}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{align*} 
 \begin{split}
 11 - 2 \times 5  &=\\
 11 - 10 &= 1
 \end{split}
 \end{align*} 

 \begin{align*}
 \begin{split}
 (3 + 2) \times (9 - 4) &=\\
 5 \times 5 &= 25
 \end{split}
 \end{align*}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: My approach was to use C++ programs to write LaTeX code for \input for the questions.  I can show you examples, if interested.  (See also http://www.elfsoft2000.com/worksheets/index.htm)

Comment: I would love to see an example, I am not completely versed in C++ but defiantly willing to learn. Thanks.

Comment: Contact me through my web site and I will email you some files.  (I may even convert the pict2e code to tikz.)